# Can not type anything in FireFox

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, cross-browser

I experience strange problem in addition to all my other problems. I am creating ASP.NET MVC application. I am using a flexigrid and attempting to use Modal dialogs. In IE, Google Chrome and Opera I can type numbers only in the Client No control, but in the FireFox I am unable to type anything.

This is how that controls renders:

```
<div id="add-edit-dialog" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; height: 622px;" scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0">
<form id="add-edit-form" novalidate="novalidate">
<fieldset>
<legend>Client Info</legend>
<input id="fntype" type="hidden" name="fntype" value="">
<input id="ClientId" type="hidden" value="" name="ClientId" data-val-number="The field ClientId must be a number." data-val="true">
<div class="editor-label" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<div class="editor-field" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<input id="ClientNumber" class="numericOnly input-validation-error" type="number" value="" name="ClientNumber" data-val-required="The Client No field is required." data-val-remote-url="/Client/doesClientNoExist" data-val-remote-type="POST" data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.ClientNumber,*.ClientId" data-val-remote="Client Number already exists. Please enter a different Client Number." data-val-number="The field Client No must be a number." data-val="true">
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="ClientNumber">
```

I am using my own class numericOnly and type number (which displays as spinner in Google Chrome).

I have CardNumbers.js file where I define numericOnly class this way:

```
$(".numericOnly").keypress(function (e) {
    if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).match(/[^0-9]/g)) return false;
});
```

The code above I found a while ago in one of the StackOverflow questions and it works Ok in other browsers.

So, do you see what may be wrong here and why I can not type anything but in FireFox only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".numericOnly").keydown(function(event) {
            // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
            if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 || 
                 // Allow: Ctrl+A
                (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) || 
                 // Allow: home, end, left, right
                (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
                     // let it happen, don't do anything
                     return;
            }
            else {
                // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
                if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 )) {
                    event.preventDefault(); 
                }   
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I am going to try your code as I noticed that my original code didn't work with TAB key. I've been testing on a small test.html file and it seems to work Ok in FireFox. I'm now back to testing from my app

Comment: Ok, after all the changes I completely broke my site :(

Comment: 1. The control now allows to type anything (both letters and numbers), but the grid is not showing up in Google Chrome or FireFox

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Just change

**from**

```
if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).match(/[^0-9]/g))
```

**to**

```
if(String.fromCharCode(e.which).match(/[^0-9]/g))
```

Comment: e.which property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode. See http://api.jquery.com/event.which/

Comment: Thanks. BTW, this change didn't help either :( Somehow FireFox embed extra class in my code and I think this is what messes it up. In my code this is what I have  
<form id="frmClientsSearch">
    <label for="clientNo">Client No: </label>
    <input type="number" name="searchClientNo" class="numericOnly" /><br />
Please see my bottom comment to user164... as how it renders. It adds novalidate tag to the form and valid class to my class. Could this be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like more of a browser issue. If your Firefox is out of date, try updating through Help > About or at http://getfirefox.com/. I just took it to an HTML testbed in Firefox v18 (latest on release channel), and it worked fine.

Comment: I was on version 17.1 which I think is quite recent. In any case, I am downloading the update now and I let you know how it goes.

Comment: Upgrading FireFox didn't help, I still can not type anything :(

Comment: I just noticed I can not type anything also on the first page (which is plain page) in the Client No input textbox, but I can type numbers only in the pager control in the flexigrid. I did change flexigrid a bit to use number and numericOnly class and the same for that control.

Comment: Here is what I found looking in FireBug:
<form id="frmClientsSearch" novalidate="novalidate">
<label for="clientNo">Client No: </label>
<input class="numericOnly valid" type="number" name="searchClientNo">
<br>
<label for="clientName">Client Name: </label>
<input class="SelectOnEntry valid" type="search" name="searchClientName" value="Please enter the search value" size="25">

Comment: Why does it add "valid" class? And this is where it works OK: 
<div class="pGroup">
<span class="pcontrol">
Page
<input class="numericOnly" type="number" value="1" size="4">
of
<span>1</span>
</span>
</div>

Comment: So, somehow FireFox adds an additional class and when it does it, the numericOnly class stops working and does nothing at all.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't stop working, it just doesn't allow me to type anything. I am wondering how can I trace KeyPress event using Firebug?